# I want to make an arcade stick USB driver for OS X

Tags: macos, driver

I have an arcade stick for my PS3 that I used for fighting games. I rarely play them anymore so I figured I'd plug the stick into my Mac and see if I could get some arcade gaming going on my computer. I have tried this on Windows too and it seems like there are no drivers for either OS.

Now, I'm not one to be disappointed and just give up like that. I thought that this would be the perfect opportunity to attempt to write a driver. How hard can it be? All I need is a plan.

**The Plan**

I want a driver that supports every function of the arcade stick. This includes:

1. Eight face buttons
2. Analog stick
3. Lock/direction switches (the latter is three steps and the former is two steps)
4. Home/Turbo buttons
5. Two side buttons

I was searching around for stuff that could help me accomplish this but I don't really know where to start. I want a tool that can scan a USB port for signals coming from a connected device and from those signals decipher what input it corresponds to. I then want to map that input programmatically to an OS X API for game controllers, put it all in a package and voilá: driver!

Maybe this only works in my head. For starters I can't find this magic USB tool that I'm looking for. I tried USB Prober and it detects my arcade stick but I can't get any log entries when I press buttons on the stick. (Yes, I installed the log kext)

Most of the search results were regarding scanning USB network interfaces. I don't think it's what I'm after.

I also got this idea that maybe USB devices behave like old school Unix devices and I'd be able to do something like `cat /dev/usb/port3` and get some good data but I have not found anything like that.

I just don't know where to start. I found some Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/intro/intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970) on USB devices but I don't even know if the stick is HID compliant.

Right now I'm mostly looking at [libusb](http://www.libusb.org) and skimming through documentation.

I haven't really dealt with this kind of project before so any ideas and tips are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most PS3 controllers are just HID devices, so you should be able to work from that direction.

A much simpler route, and less personally satisfying I suppose, would be to just grab one of the USB->Mac game controller applications and run with that.

I've used [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) for years and it always seems to work well.